# Uniqueness of limit proof without epsilon/2

Tags: real-analysis

I see that in proofs a lot they will use epsilon / 2 so that at the end, lets say for the uniqueness of a limit, they will have epsilon / 2 + epsilon / 2 = epsilon which looks nice at the end.

Now, since epsilon is arbitrary, can we technically have instead epsilon/3 or epsilon/ 4 lets say. If so, how would we use that value to still prove that the uniqueness of limits?

Comment: Please give an example of a proof that confused you. Anyway, it helps to note that these epsilons just have to be "good enough".

Comment: Yes, you could do that as long as the sum is no larger than $\epsilon$. Example: $\dfrac{\epsilon}{5} + \dfrac{4\epsilon}{5} = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific proof you are referencing we prove that every sequence $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a unique limit by contradiction.

Too quickly write out the proof so I have something concrete to reference, we assume first that there exists a sequence with two limits $l_1$ and $l_2$ such that $l_1\neq l_2$. We choose $\epsilon =\frac{|l_1-l_2|}{2}$.

Now we apply the definition of limits and say there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\geq M, |l_1-a_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|l_2-a_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Finally using the triangle inequality we can say:
$$\begin{aligned}|l_1-l_2|&\leq|l_1-a_n|+|a_n-l_2|\\|l_1-l_2|&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\|l_1-l_2|&<\epsilon=\frac{|l_1-l_2|}{2}\end{aligned}$$

A contradiction.

The initial 'choice' of epsilon is arbitrary, we can make it anything we like but for this proof some fraction of $|l_1-l_2|$ works nicely.

For our next choice of epsilon in the definition of our limits, it makes sense to choose $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ because, as you say, it looks nice at the end but we can also see that any fraction of $\epsilon$ will work since finding that any fraction of $|l_1-l_2|$ is greater than $|l_1-l_2|$ itself will yield the same contradiction.

For me, it also helps to think exactly what’s going on, what we are saying is that there exists a distance between the two limits since they are not equal, but because of the definition of limits I can always choose a value of epsilon such that it would be impossible for the sequence to be close enough to both limits to satisfy the definition. Try and see how the proof illustrates this idea.

Hope this answers your question.